# FileSystemWatcher 1000+ individual client machines

Tags: c#, popup, filesystemwatcher

I recently created a winform app that has a FileSystemWatcher that points to a single directory on a network drive that contains a single (max 4kb) txt file and has the NotifyFilter set to "LastWrite".

The form starts hidden but if the txt file is updated the app reads each line of the file into a string array, sets the lines as the text property of various text boxes then animates a "pop up" of the form above the notification area before hiding again on a timer.

I made a webfront end that writes to the txt file and in effect "Sends" the message to all of the users running the app when the form is submitted.

We have been using this on a team of approx 30 to send notification messages for the last month or so with no issues and not a single missed message.

I am now being asked if this can be expanded to be able to send the same notifications to an audience of 1000+ users and i'm starting to think maybe that's not such a good idea?

What sort of overhead does FSW have on the network/fileserver where the file is hosted?

Are there any (free) ready made client/server solutions to save me re-inventing the wheel?

We only use it to send 5-10 messages a week at most so I don't really want to go crazy developing something way outside the spec of what we need.

Comment: A simple webservice that pushes messages to the client will take a couple of hours of development time and is more flexible/scalable if it ever needs to.

Comment: I started looking into Websockets and SignalR but couldnt help feel like it was overkill to what I need.

Are there any technical limitations of using FSW on that scale that would make the current app un-viable?

Comment: @prwilliams1982 I don't consider SignalR overkill and is much more reliable, as FSW may fail sometimes. It's not even that hard to implement. A couple of hours for someone familiar with it, a few more if you never used it

Comment: The question about ready-made solutions might be off-topic, but the actual question "will this scale, and if not, why?" is very interesting . The documentation on FileSystemWatcher (and the underlying ReadDirectoryChangesW) is definitely not clear on what the overhead would be on the fileserver.

Comment: Of course the comments suggesting using a more appropriate technique for messaging are spot-on, but that doesn't invalidate the technical question.

Comment: Exactly, I know this isn't an ideal solution but it it will work without me making any changes with no overhead then it would suit my requirements in this instance

Comment: @prwilliams1982 Whether it will work or not is unclear. If you can test without much effort, it will not harm to give a try, and fall back to another solution in case it fails. If you do try, please give us a feedback.

Comment: I spent sometime yesterday looking at SignalR and got to say its pretty cool.....

I think looking at the older websockets documentation had initially scared me off but I had my SignalR server/client configured in less than an hour and has opened up a whole new world of possibilities (groups for targeted messages to start with).

Thanks for the sugestion!